# Synchronizing app widget's layout with another dynamically created layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-appwidget

I have a `Fragment` within my `Activity` which is created dynamically from an almost blank layout.xml, which only holds a `LinearLayout` and a `RelativeLayout`. Their contents are created at runtime on the user's behalf.

I'd like to synchronize my app widget's layout with the `Fragment`'s, so the app widget will look the same after every change within the `Fragment`. Those changes are being saved in `SharedPreferences`, so the `Fragment` will look the same on next initialization. The reason why I'm using the `Fragment` is because I want to be able to respond on actions like `onLongClick()`.

So I'm looking for a way to update my app widget's layout with the recently added `Views` (e.g. a `Button`).

Comment: "Their contents are created at runtime on the user's behalf." - You are letting the users create UI elements, right? They have some sort of "palette" of UI elements to choose?

Comment: Kind of - there is a plus-button, which is supposed to add new buttons to the widget, when clicked. Sorry for the late answer, currently I don't have much time for this project.

Comment: No problem, if you don't mind another question before answering yours. "The reason why I'm using the Fragment is because I want to be able to respond on actions like onLongClick()": can't understand this, the reason to use Fragments is to take advantage of a certain gesture like a long press?